# Creating a dynamic URL in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a contact us page on Joomla and have a form therein,on submitting the form it saves the info to the database.
And suppose the record id of the newly created contact is 100,
After saving I want to generate a URL that appends this record id.
Eg : www.helpme.com/contactus/100 or anything like that.
How do I do that in Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

The url to display a single contact with the contact id=100 in Joomla 3.x looks like this:

```
http://yourdomainname.com/index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=100
```